# line-height in paragraphs with very large text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, accessibility

Bootstrap provides a way to adjust the font size of a paragraph text so that it looks very large; e.g. the size and style of a heading without actually using a heading level HTML tag.

I don't *want* to use a real `<H2>` tag just to affect the visual presentation of this text because **it is secondary, stand-alone text in the site footer, and doesn't have anything following or preceding it, and I don't want to affect the document outline**.

```html
<p class="h2">This is a very large stand-alone slogan text.</p>
```

[image: example text]

However, I'm getting warnings from accessibility checkers that state:

> The line-height for paragraphs should be at least 1.5 times the font size.

The underlying success criteria on visual presentation from W3C is here:

https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/visual-presentation.html

> Line spacing (leading) is at least space-and-a-half within paragraphs, and paragraph spacing is at least 1.5 times larger than the line spacing.

The issue here is that heading styles on this site have a line height of 1.2, which look good and have plenty of whitespace.

Therefore, I believe this is being flagged as a false positive.

Is there a recommended approach to avoid this being flagged with the line-height warning above?  Should I switch to a `<div>` or another HTML5 tag?  Thoughts?

Comment: The accessibility checker in question is siteimprove.com  Here is the details they provide, which are less than helpful really... https://alfa.siteimprove.com/rules/sia-r73

Comment: If switching to another tag makes a difference, get rid of the accessibility checker, because that shouldn't be a relevant factor. Note that the WCAG requirement asks for space and a half, not font size and a half. so if a regular single line spacing is 1.2 times the font-size, the line spacing would need to be 1.8 times the font-size. But in any case, this is definitely a false positive. It applies to "blocks of text", which is defined as more than one sentence. You have just one.

Comment: I'm confused by what you're saying @Alohci. W3C says "Line spacing (leading) is at least space-and-a-half within paragraphs", which translates to `line-height: 1.5` does it not?

Comment: He means that spacing before a paragraph (so if you have multiple paragraphs for example) should be at least 1.5 times the line height. So if your `line-height` was 1.5 your **paragraph spacing** should be 2.25 (1.5 * 1.5). The last sentence they added was the most important here, this rule does not apply as it is not a "block of text" just a single sentence. Hopefully that is clear.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie -- no, the first part of that is not what I meant. The description in the WCAG doc says "By **space and a half within paragraphs** we mean that top of one line is 150% further from the top of the line below it than would be true when the text is 'single spaced' (the default spacing for the font)." The text would be single spaced when the line-height was "normal", which is typically around 1.2 * font-size. So space and a half = 1.5 * 1.2 * font-size. The spacing between paragraphs would then need to be 1.5 * 1.5 * 1.2 * font-size = 2.7 * font-size.

Comment: @Alohci Jeez you are right, I am now going to have to go unpick all of that as a `line-height` of 1.5 is acceptable (according to pretty much every accessibility checker and article), so is that `1.5 x "single spacing"` when I set the `line-height` and I just never noticed in all these years? What an interesting thing to have never noticed / picked up on until you just pointed it out to me!

Answer (score 3):

### Should I use a different element?

Continue to use a paragraph, that is most likely the most semantically correct element. Switching to a different element (especially a `<div>` without any WAI-ARIA to give it a `role`) is likely to mean that you break the semantics of the document.

With that being said, it is not entirely clear from a screenshot of text whether a `<p>` is the most appropriate element so take this advice as "likely to be correct" rather than definitive!

### Does SC 1.4.8 actually apply here?

As pointed out in a comment this rule applies to "blocks of text".

> **blocks of text**
>
> more than one sentence of text

As this is a single sentence in the footer with no surrounding text it does not apply here.

### Any other WCAG rules to be aware of?

Although SC 1.4.8 almost certainly does not apply, [SC 1.4.12 Text Spacing](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/text-spacing) **does** still apply so you need to be aware of that.

So you need to ensure that someone can override your styles with the following settings and it is still readable and doesn't overlap any other items:

- Line height (line spacing) to at least 1.5 times the font size;
- Spacing following paragraphs to at least 2 times the font size;
- Letter spacing (tracking) to at least 0.12 times the font size;
- Word spacing to at least 0.16 times the font size.

You should be able to set **all** of the above at the same time and it still be readable.

### Can I get rid of the error?

As far as I am aware siteimprove only allows you to remove whole pages from their crawl process so you will just have to manually ignore this point. I did have a quick look through the docs to see if this has changed since we stopped using it but couldn't find anything.

Perhaps contact them and see if there is a way to ignore this as it is a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend simply using [another HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element). A `<div>` is probably most appropriate, although you could consider a [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) or an [`<aside>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside).

If this particular accessibility checker warning becomes a consistent annoyance (and it really is a non-problem), you could of course silence it.